# Linq equivalent of sql statement from one table but including counts based on groups within that table

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

Sorry for the horrible title, I don't know the correct terminology to use.

I have a simple table (called materials):

```
Id       int
Desc     Varchar(50)
MainType Varchar(20)
SubType  Varchar(20)
```

Some sample data:

```
ID     Desc                    Maintype     SubType
1      Aluminium 3003          Metal        Aluminium
2      Bamboo                  Wood         Softwood
3      Cellulose Acetate       Polymer      CA
4      Cork                    Wood         Composite
5      Stainless Steel         Metal        Steel
6      Tinplate                Metal        Steel
7      PA (Type 11, Unfilled)  Polymer      PA
8      PA (Type 12, Unfilled)  Polymer      PA
9      PA (Type 46, Extrusion) Polymer      PA
10     Palm                    Wood         Softwood
```

I simply want an ordered (by maintype, subtype) list of materials (ungrouped) and including the number of occurrences of each of that materials maintypes and subtypes in the dataset, like so:

```
ID     Desc                    Maintype     SubType    CountMain   CountSub
1      Aluminium 3003          Metal        Aluminium  3           1
5      Stainless Steel         Metal        Steel      3           2
6      Tinplate                Metal        Steel      3           2
3      Cellulose Acetate       Polymer      CA         4           1
7      PA (Type 11, Unfilled)  Polymer      PA         4           3
8      PA (Type 12, Unfilled)  Polymer      PA         4           3
9      PA (Type 46, Extrusion) Polymer      PA         4           3
4      Cork                    Wood         Composite  3           1
2      Bamboo                  Wood         Softwood   3           2
10     Palm                    Wood         Softwood   3           2
```

In SQL this is a doddle:

```
SELECT Id
      ,MaterialName
      ,MaterialType
      ,MaterialSubType
      ,(select count(id) from materials m2 where m2.materialType=m1.materialType) as CountMain
      ,(select count(id) from materials m2 where m2.materialSubType=m1.materialSubType) as CountSub
  FROM materials m1
  order by materialType, MaterialSubType
```

However in Linq I cannot get anywhere near it. That may be because I use vb and there are some syntactical difficulties with group and into. I can't even get a clean compilation of the linq expression as I cannot work out the fiendish contextual problems caused by "group" and "into" and "count".  As I don't know the correct technical terms for the subQueries I use for the "count" results I just can't find any examples that do this.  Maybe it's because I'm doing it wrong!

I'm sure it will be quite simple for someone who understands linq queries - if there's an online tutorial or something that would show me how to achieve this, I'd appreciate a pointer or a brief explanation of how to do this in LINQ please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sods law, I worked it out just after posting that!

```
from mat in materials 
order by mat.mainType, mat.subType
select new with {
    mat.Id,
    mat.MaterialName,
    mat.MainType,
    mat.SubType,
    .countMain = (Aggregate m2 in materials
                    where m2.MainType=mat.MainType
                    into Count()),
    .countSub = (Aggregate m2 in materials
                    where m2.SubType=mat.SubType
                    into Count())
}
```